# Is it a good practice to use Enum for the type field in STI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a requirement to list all the **type** values of STI. So I would like to maintain all the possible values of **type**.

Is it a good practice to make the **type** field an Enum in the parent class?

Comment: Can you post some code so we can get a better understanding of what you're planning to do?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a requirement to list all the type values of STI. So I would
>   like to maintain all the possible values of type.

```
class ParentClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.sti_types
    @sti_types ||= self.select(:type).distinct
  end
end
```

> Is it a good practice to make the type field an Enum in the parent class?

I assume you mean, the database enum type, if that's the case, the answer is no, because it does not give you the flexibility to add new classes as you wish, this means if you want a new class, you would have to *migrate* the enum column to add this new value.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is a good idea, because if later you add a new record with new type, you have to manually update the `enum`, if you just want to know all the current type values in the table you can simple make a method like this:

```
def
  your_model_name.distinct.pluck(:type)
end
```

Comment: hi if you find it helpful please accept my solution :)

Comment: The point of an enum is not simply to list the different values in a column. The primary point of an enum is to make database queries on a large table faster by storing integers rather than strings. (It does happen to be true that Rails gives you a few advantages on the side when you use enums.) You are right that this is a good answer to OP if OP's only reason for thinking of an enum is to simply list the values. On the other hand, adding an enum in an STI case could still be a good idea if done for the performance reasons I've mentioned.